# Migrate API: map fields outside the item_selector

Tags: 8, migrations

I'm working on a migration of a JSON with this format:

```
{
  "departement": "19",
  "conseillers": [
    {
     "code": "A24",
     "nom": "DUNAC",
     "prenom": "Roger",
    },
    {
     "code": "A25",
     "nom": "DUNAX",
     "prenom": "Roged",
    },
    { ... }
  ],
}
```

I'm using the URL plugin with JSON

```
source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: http
  data_parser_plugin: json
  item_selector: conseillers
```

There is no problem mapping each element inside the group: [conseillers]

```
fields:
    -
      name: code
      label: 'Code identifiant technique du conseiller'
      selector: /code
```

But the rest api moves to the parent level the global information like "department"

So, How can I map the "conseiller" value which is outside the item_selector?

Thanks!